# What is a good way to store global site settings in Rails that are editable by an admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a rails portfolio application which only has an admin(s) to manage the site. The admin should for example be able to change the site name or the header image. What is a good way to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

I personally like to use the singleton pattern in that case. It's basically a class that you have only one instance. So we could call it SystemSetting, for example, and add the attributes for the settings as as you like. I believe this article could give you some direction about singleton in ruby: http://dalibornasevic.com/posts/9-ruby-singleton-pattern-again. Good luck!